# Option tag not inserting values in MongoDB using React and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to achieve inserting the option value tags using MERN, but whenever I tried to insert in the database it inserts nothing, I can't seem to find the issue. I just started learning MERN. Anyways this is the code I wrote. Any help will deeply be appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

```
export default class AddClient extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeExisting = this.onChangeExisting.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      existing: "",
    };
  }

  onChangeExisting(e) {
    this.setState({
      existing: e.target.value,
    });
  }


  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const client = {
      existing: this.state.existing,
    };

    console.log(client);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/clients/create", client)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Existing Customer: </label>
                      <select
                        ref="userInput"
                        required
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.existing}
                        onChange={this.onChangeExisting}
                      >
                        <option key="Male" value="Male">
                          Male
                        </option>
                        <option key="Female" value="Female">
                          Female
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
              <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>submit </button> 
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I find no issues here. Could you share your server code for the route you mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it just has to change put data instead of e

```
 onChangeExisting(e) {
    this.setState({
      existing: e.target.value,
    });
  }
```

to

```
 onChangeExisting(data) {
    this.setState({
      existing: data.value,
    });
  }
```

and putting a variable like this:

```
const existing= [
  { key: "Not Started", label: "Not Started", value: "Not Started" },
  { key: "In Progress", label: "In Progress", value: "In Progress" },
  { key: "Completed", label: "Completed", value: "Completed" },
];
```

and calling it via:

```
npm i react-select
```

`then import Select from "react-select";` on the page you want to use it

```
<Select options={existing} onChange={this.onChangeExisting} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`You dont Have <button> Tag in side a <form> tag .`

so when & how submit event can call?
pls Add

```
<button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>submit </button>
```

inside form tag.

Comment: oh sorry it actually is there maybe accidentally removed it